# Replace existing file on MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an existing file "abc.pdf" on production: c:\inetpub\www\secure\mywebsite\files\abc.pdf

I would like to replace this to: c:\inetpub\www\secure\mywebsite\files\def.pdf

do I make this changes in visual studio and build and run, or do I just go straight to the c:\inetpub folder and simply replacing the file?

Comment: Unless the PDF file is somehow part of the code, there's probably no need to re-build and re-deploy the application.  If it's just a content file, simply replace the file.  If, however, you're changing the *name* of the file and there's code which references that *name*, you'd need to change that.  If that name is changeable then the value in the code should be a config value.

Comment: Is this file linked on any page of your program?

Comment: so on my website we have it listed as click "here" to download the file.

Comment: @Menew: If it's a new version of an existing document, you just replace the old file with the new file.  Keep the same file name.  If it's an entirely new document that needs to be linked in the code somewhere, you'll need to change the code to link to it.

Comment: Hi David, I am replacing an existing file. so i can rename it to match the existing file. by going to c:\inetpub\www on production and making the change, is safe correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it outside of visual studio, you'll have to unhide the files and then include it in your project. If you do it within visual studio, it automatically includes it for you. Although this wouldn't make much of a difference since it's just a file, the app will read it whether included in the project or not. But hey, might as well.

And needless to say, you'll have to update the references.

Comment: so how do i do it in visual studio? i am using visual studio 2012. thanks.

Comment: but how does it get it copied over? the actual file? it is on my desktop, how does visual studio know? so in my solution explorer its under files: oldfile.pdf, the new file is on my desktop, how do i make the switch?

Comment: Draaaaag and then DROP!! :)

Comment: got it, when i mouse over it, i saw the path of the file on my pc, so i will drop it in there. then build and run and upload to production. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a PDF file, you can simply use Windows Explorer to swap it out.

**EDIT**

You may want to update your file in your Visual Studio project if it exists there, so that a future deployment doesn't overwrite what you copy over.

Comment: thats what i figured, so how do i update it in visual studio? i tried to google it and didn't find anything on it. thanks.